# How to fix failure when receiving data with curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get the html code of the home page of the australian verison of yellow pages using CURL but i'm having a curl error. 
The below error is generated everytime.

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.yellowpages.com.au/
*   Trying 104.94.32.193...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.yellowpages.com.au (104.94.32.193) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: D:\projects\my_site\webroot/cacert-2019-01-23.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=AU; ST=Victoria; L=Melbourne; O=Sensis Pty Ltd; OU=SSL Administration; OU=Unified Communications; CN=*.whitepages.com.au
*  start date: Oct  4 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*  expire date: Sep  5 23:59:59 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.yellowpages.com.au" matched cert's "*.yellowpages.com.au"
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yellowpages.com.au
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept: */*

  Curl error: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054cURL error (56):
 Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

I cannot find what i missed.

```
$url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com.au';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cacert-2019-01-23.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); //Wait forever
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
$error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found, with your code ( apart from missing final closing brace ) that it requires the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option set

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
```

That said, when it then ran it  produced

> Curl error: Could not resolve host: www.yellowpages.com.aucURL error
>   (6): Couldn't resolve host name

I tried a different curl function and then also with `Postman` and received

> We have detected unusual traffic activity originating from your IP
>   address.

Comment: Thank you, means that this is yellow pages which block external connection?

Comment: it might just have been my ip that was blocked ( until I did a google captcha which then set a cookie ). Try with Postman for yourself perhaps - least you know then if the curl code is at fault or not

Comment: I tried with Postman and it works but cannot reproduce the same code. Got the captcha as well.